# Add a image to Header of Flex Panel component

Tags: apache-flex

I want to replace the default title of the header with my image in Flex Panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't actually think this is possible with the built in panel. My recommendation would be to either create your own container that allows you to put an image in the header (quite complicated) or to create a composite component that has an image for its header and an area to add content e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:VBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" >
        <mx:Image src="someImage.jpg" />
        <mx:Canvas>
            <!-- add content here -->           
        </mx:Canvas>
</mx:VBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but panels have the property titleIcon which can be set to a class to do this.

```
titleIcon="@Embed('img/image.png')"
```